# Two Multicast Questions

Tags: linux, multicast

It's about Socket-Programming in Linux:

When I send a Message to a Multicast Group, Which I am also a member of, will I get my own message too?

Is there any way to send a e.g. text-string as multicast-message to a multicast group over the Linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> When I send a Message to a Multicast Group, Which I am also a member of, will I get my own message too?

It depends on the setting of the loopback option.

> Is there any way to send a e.g. text-string as multicast-message to a multicast group over the Linux terminal?

A string is just data. You can multicast any data. 'Over a Linux terminal' is meaningless.

Comment: I think he mend if there is something like `echo foo | netcat --multicast 239.239.239.1 1234`. Is there?